# localstorage overwrites after refresh

Tags: angular, storage, local, ionic4

So,i  have a json file Uid stands for userID

```
    const ChartData = {
     dayId: this.dayId,
     calories: this.burned,
     date: this.jstoday
    };

    this.dataService.setData(this.Uid, ChartData);
```

i save the data on localstorage using a dataService Where i create an empty array(ChartTable) and i save this array to the localstorage with key the userID,And each time a user adds data to the storage i push his data to the ChartData table.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class DataService {

  private data = [];
  private ChartTable = [];

  constructor(private storage: Storage) { }

  setData(Uid, data) {

    this.data[Uid] = data;


    this.SaveData(Uid, this.data[Uid]);

  }

  getData(id) {
    return this.data[id];
  }

  SaveData(Uid, data) {
    //Pushing eachDay's data to table
    this.ChartTable.push(data);

    //Need to stringify to work
    this.storage.set(Uid, JSON.stringify(this.ChartTable));
    // Or to get a key/value pair
  }
 }
```

When i keep adding items to the array they are been pushed in the ChartTable array and its working correctly.Then i go to the profile page check the localstorage and show a chart to the user.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import chartJs from 'chart.js';
import { Auth2Service } from 'src/app/services/auth2.service';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Calendar } from '@ionic-native/calendar/ngx';
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications/ngx';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.page.scss'],


})
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('barCanvas') barCanvas;

  ChartData = [];
  ChartDataLength: any;

  public val: any;
  private Uid: string;

  Calories = [];
  Dates = [];
  BackgroundColors = [];

  barChart: any;

  today = new Date();
  followingDay = new Date();

  jstoday = '';

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public auth: Auth2Service,
    private localNotifications: LocalNotifications,
    private calendar: Calendar,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private storage: Storage

  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.checkForUser();

    // Schedule a single notification
    this.localNotifications.schedule({
      text: 'Delayed ILocalNotification',
      trigger: { at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600) },
      led: 'FF0000',
      sound: null
    });

    this.calendar.createCalendar('MyCalendar').then(
      (msg) => { console.log(msg); },
      (err) => { console.log(err); }
    );

  }

  getChart(context, chartType, data, options?) {
    return new chartJs(context, {
      data,
      options,
      type: chartType
    })
  }

  getBarChart(Calories, Dates, BackgroundColors) {

    const data = {
      labels: Dates,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'number of calories you burned',
        data: Calories,
        backgroundColor: BackgroundColors,
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    };

    const options = {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }

    return this.getChart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, 'bar', data, options);

  }

  checkForUser() {

    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {

      if (user) {
        this.Uid = user.uid;

        this.val = this.storage.get(this.Uid).then((val) => {

          this.ChartData = JSON.parse(val);

          if (this.ChartData != null) {

            this.ChartData = Object.keys(this.ChartData).map(key => ({ type: key, value: this.ChartData[key] }));

            this.ChartDataLength = this.ChartData.length;

            for (let i = 0; i < this.ChartDataLength; i++) {
              this.Calories[i] = this.ChartData[i].value.calories;
              this.Dates[i] = this.ChartData[i].value.date;
              this.BackgroundColors[i] = 'rgb(0, 249, 186   )';
            }

            this.barChart = this.getBarChart(this.Calories, this.Dates, this.BackgroundColors);

          }

        });
      }
    });

  }

  logoutUser() {
    this.auth.logoutUser();
  }
}
```

The problem is that when i refresh the page and go to add an other item to the ChartTable it gets overwritten and only the new data is shown to the chart.Do you know how can i solve this issue?

Comment: The problem is the local storage data is not loaded, while the JS objects are “reset” on the page load. So every time a *new* (per reload) array is saved. Load / merge existing data first so it is not overwritten.

Comment: How can i load the data first? @user2864740

Answer (score -1):

When you reload the app, your app re-initializes and all your existing data go off from memory. So you need to reset it back to your DataService's ChartTable. You can do it right after getting it back from localstorage.

```
if (this.ChartData != null) {

            this.ChartData = Object.keys(this.ChartData).map(key => ({ type: key, value: this.ChartData[key] }));

            this.ChartDataLength = this.ChartData.length;
            this.dataService.ChartTable = this.ChartData;

          }
```

You need to inject DataService into your component and you need to either write getter and setter on ChartTable or make it as public.

Comment: Doesnt work.I cant get it back from local storage after the refresh.there is nothing to get back.what to you mean by setter and getter?

Comment: Then you need to debug your code while setting the value to local storage. This local storage's set method returns promise. Inside then block you need to check if value is stored in localstorage or not.